# $\Sigma^1_1$-complete set of natural numbers of non-logical nature

Tags: combinatorics, logic, computability, decision-problems

I am interested in $\Sigma^1_1$-complete reals (i.e., subsets of $\omega$) of non-logical nature. I am more familiar with $\Sigma^1_1$-complete *sets* of reals that arise in computable structure theory, but I have recently realized that I knew of no reals of similar vein.

1. A host of reals that are $\Sigma^1_1$-complete appear to come from so-called [*recurring domino problems.*](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dharel/SCANNED.PAPERS/RucurringDominoes.pdf) These are variants of the better known tiling problem by Wang:  in the recurrent domino problems, you ask whether there is a tiling in which a designated color occurs infinitely many times in the top row.  The linked paper studies three variants of the problem, but one could think of more.  In fact, in a more [recent paper](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/papers/fsttcs10.pdf), a variant in which the number of colors is finite and there is a restriction on the tiles is called "the recurrent [*sic*] domino problem."  My question is: is there a good survey of these sets of reals?  Often, these were published in old CS conference proceedings, so they are scattered and sometimes very hard to obtain.  (In fact, I can't read the article cited in Vardi et al. even though it appears to contain a stronger result.)
2. More generally, I am interested in $\Sigma^1_1$-complete reals of non-logical nature.  Is there a survey of such reals?  The recurring domino problems are combinatorial, but I would not be surprised if people have looked at $\Sigma^1_1$-complete reals arising from, say, finite group theory.

Comment: Generally a set of reals arising in computable structure theory has an analogous set of naturals: if $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of reals coding structures with some property $P$, we can also look at the set $S$ of natural numbers coding computable structures with property $P$. There's a bit of a mismatch here since the set of indices of structures is itself not computable, and so sometimes it's convenient to look at partial structures, but this isn't an issue once we go to complexity levels above $\Pi^0_2$.

Comment: There are also sets of naturals arising in computable structure theory which intuitively precede their analogous sets of reals: e.g. the set of codes for computably categorical structures is a $\Pi^1_1$-complete set of naturals, and the analogous set of reals (the set of relatively computably categorical structures) arguably isn't as directly motivated.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your comments.  Reals defined by using indices of computable functions are not exactly what I had in mind as "non-logical" reals, but then again my question was inherently vague (I'm sure the recurring domino problems hide indices in them in a clever way).

Comment: Yeah, I knew that wasn't what you were looking for, but given that you mentioned computable structure theory I thought it worth mentioning.